# How to pass query results into Amchart?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, amcharts

Please consider the following code:

*Following tag inside header of my file*

```
<script>

var chart;

var chartData = [{
    ConnectionType: "First",
    NumberPercentage: 1194,
{
    ConnectionType: "Second",
    NumberPercentage: 1882},
{
    ConnectionType: "Third",
    NumberPercentage: 1809},
{
    ConnectionType: "Fourth",
    NumberPercentage: 1322},
{
    ConnectionType: "Fifth",
    NumberPercentage: 1122},
{
    ConnectionType: "Sixth",
    NumberPercentage: 1114},
{
    ConnectionType: "Seventh",
    NumberPercentage: 984}
    ];


AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // PIE CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();

    // title of the chart
    chart.addTitle("3D Donut Charts", 16);

    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.titleField = "ConnectionType";
    chart.valueField = "NumberPercentage";
    chart.sequencedAnimation = true;
    chart.startEffect = "elastic";
    chart.innerRadius = "30%";
    chart.startDuration = 2;
    chart.labelRadius = 15;

    // the following two lines makes the chart 3D
    chart.depth3D = 10;
    chart.angle = 15;

    // WRITE                                 
    chart.write("chartdiv");
});

</script>
```

Following tag inside body tag of my profile:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 362px;"></div>
```

I want to return the data from the following `cfquery` in my ColdFusion file. For the sake of simplicity I'm only mentioning `cfquery` for First connection. Rest cfqueries till seventh are same except the names.

```
<cfquery datasource = "XX.XX.X.XX" name="qCFCHART">
SELECT
   Count(*) AS TOTAL_CONNECTION
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'FIRST'  = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS FIRST
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'SECOND' = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS SECOND
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'THIRD'  = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS THIRD
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'FOURTH' = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS FOURTH
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'FIFTH'  = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS FIFTH
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'SIXTH'  = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS SIXTH
,  Sum(CASE WHEN 'SEVENTH'  = EVENTS THEN 100 END) / Count(*) AS SEVENTH
   FROM MyDatabase;
</cfquery>
```

Considering the code from above script:

```
ConnectionType: "First",
NumberPercentage: 1194,
```

I want to display the result returned by "FIRST" from the above query into my Pie Chart and writing `cfdump` or anything ColdFusion related doesn't work there.

For example:

```
ConnectionType: "First",
NumberPercentage: <cfdump var="#qCFCHART.FIRST#>",
```

The above throws an error and I see an obvious reason because I'm inside script tag and I'm wondering how to proceed? Any suggestions?

Here is my attempt after following some comments:

```
<cfoutput query="qCFCHART">
    #currentrow#)
    <cfloop index="col" list="#columnlist#">
            #col#=#qCFCHART[col][currentRow]#
    </cfloop>
    <p/>
</cfoutput>


<cfset cols = getMetadata(qCFCHART)>
<cfdump var="#cols#">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to loop over the query and create a data structure similar to what the chart is expecting - which appears to be an array of structures.

I am not going to give you the code to do this as it is a fairly simple operation, and one you could easily find information on if you choose to look for it.

You can then use serialzeJSON( data ) to get the JSON version of your data - which should have the same structure as `chartData` in your sample code.

Comment: You mentioned in your comment that I need to loop over the query first and then use serializeJSON(data). However, if I first use serializeJSON(data), I can see the JSON formatted results in my browser but still wondering how to extract specific values from that format. Please let me know if I'm heading in right direction?

P.S: I have no experience with jQuery if it's required.

Comment: So, you willingly did not follow my suggestion and are then asking me why it did not work? You cannot just do serializeJSON() on your query (which it seems you are saying) and expect it to be in the same format that your chart is expecting. You do not need to use jQuery if you follow what I did, you can simply set the value of serializeJSON(data) to a JavaScript variable `<script> var moo = <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(data)#</cfoutput>;</script>`

Comment: I didn't do anything willingly and my only intention was to clarify my question. I have updated the code in my original post and I can see the array of structures as the output after the execution of `<cfset cols = getMetadata(qCFCHART)>
<cfdump var="#cols#">` code. Please let me know if I'm heading in right direction? 2) If I use serializeJSON(cols) here then it just displays arrays of structures in JSON format. Let me know if something is wrong hat I'm doing. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `getMetaData()` on the query? I can say, unequivocally, that you are heading in the wrong direction using that. You need to take the values in the query and convert them to a format that your chart will understand, which is an array of structures. So, you need to create an array, then create a structure for each item you want to display with the keys 'ConnectionType' and 'NumberPercentage', respectively, and append this structure to the array for each item you want to display on your chart. Then use cfoutput and serializeJSON() to set the value of chartData in your JS block

Comment: If there is anything in my above response that you do not understand, you need to take a step back and learn some of the basics before you proceed, because nothing I stated is difficult or complex to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is output values from your server-side coldfusion query into your client-side javascript.  e.g

```
<cfoutput>
var chartData = [{
    ConnectionType: "First",
    NumberPercentage: #qCFCHART.FIRST#},
{
    ConnectionType: "Second",
    NumberPercentage:  #qCFCHART.Second#},
{
    ConnectionType: "Third",
    NumberPercentage:  #qCFCHART.Third#},
{
    ConnectionType: "Fourth",
    NumberPercentage:  #qCFCHART.Fourth#},
{
    ConnectionType: "Fifth",
    NumberPercentage:  #qCFCHART.Fifth#},
{
    ConnectionType: "Sixth",
    NumberPercentage:  #qCFCHART.Sixth#},
{
    ConnectionType: "Seventh",
    NumberPercentage:  #qCFCHART.Seventh#}
    ];
</cfoutput>
```

The main reason your cfdump approach might not have worked is because you have a syntax error here:

```
<cfdump var="#qCFCHART.FIRST#>"
```

Should have been

```
<cfdump var="#qCFCHART.FIRST#">
```

But I'd strongly recommend against using cfdump; just output the value normally, there shouldn't be any need to 'dump' values into production code.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix to this question was that I needed to mention `<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(qCFCHART.First)#</cfoutput>` after Number Percentage field and it worked fine.

Comment: This is a very poor approach to the problem you are trying to solve. Scott has given you the better answer.